# Move an image on a UIView in iOS Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

---

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // name of image
    self.imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"];
    [self.view addSubview: self.imageview];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    self.imageview.center = touchLocation;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // get touch event
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.mytransperentview];
    if ([touch view] == self.imageview)
    {
        self.imageview.center = touchLocation;
    }
}
```

---

1. The image is moving but its not moving freely.

---

Comment: Without a clear question, this is likely to be closed quickly.

Comment: @Caleb Hah. He asked the question in the end technically ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Silly mistake**: Replace `self.imageview` with `self.view` in `touchesMoved` method. It will work fine, and move the image smoothly when you drag. See line 42 -

[image]

I tested your code and discovered it. Here is my test code, if it helps -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    self.imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
    [self.imageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageview];

}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    self.imageview.center = touchLocation;

    if ([touch.view isEqual: self.view] || touch.view == nil) {
        return;
    }

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    if ([touch.view isEqual: self.view]) {

         self.imageview.center = touchLocation;

        return;
    }
}
```